# Repeated measures ANOVA with custom standard errors

Tags: regression, anova, repeated-measures

I want to see if there's a difference in size of some cells after several measurements, compared to a baseline (0.5, 1, 3, 6 hours versus 0 hours). I have 3 samples. Each measurement is actually a mean of diameters of many cells and I have the corresponding standard error. I think a repeated measures ANOVA or multiple regression may be suitable here but I cannot figure out how (and whether) to introduce the custom standard errors into the actual calculations(the program assumes a sample of 3 rather than several hundred cells).
Could someone help me use the errors? I have access to SPSS 22 and R. I may get access to Statsoft Statistica 10 and Graphpad Prism 5.